# How do I center a column of right aligned numbers in a CSS grid column?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using a CSS grid to display a table of numeric data. In a given column, I'd like all of the numeric data to be right aligned but centered within the space allocated for the column. In other words, it should look something like this.

[image]

I want the Price and Discount columns to have the same width and the prices to be right aligned to each other and then centered in the column.

This is my first attempt and the result.

HTML

```
<div class="product-table">
  <div class="first-column">Item</div>
  <div class="middle-column">Price</div>
  <div class="last-column">Discount</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget A</div>
  <div class="middle-column">2.00</div>
  <div class="last-column">0.50</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget B</div>
  <div class="middle-column">2,000.00</div>
  <div class="last-column">2.50</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget C</div>
  <div class="middle-column">3,000,000.00</div>
  <div class="last-column">3,000.00</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 1fr;
}

.first-column {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.middle-column {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.last-column {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

[image]

The columns are sized like I want them but the numbers are not aligned correctly.

My next attempt was to use auto for the column size and empty divs to pad out the column.

HTML.

```
<div class="product-table">
  <div class="first-column">Item</div>
  <div></div><div class="middle-column-title">Price</div><div></div>
  <div class="last-column">Discount</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget A</div>
  <div></div><div class="middle-column">2.00</div><div></div>
  <div class="last-column">0.50</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget B</div>
  <div></div><div class="middle-column">2,000.00</div><div></div>
  <div class="last-column">2.50</div>

  <div class="first-column">Widget C</div>
  <div></div><div class="middle-column">3,000,000.00</div><div></div>
  <div class="last-column">3,000.00</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 0.4fr auto 0.4fr 1fr;
}

.first-column {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.middle-column-title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.middle-column {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.last-column {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

This results in something pretty close to what I want, but the column width is 0.4fr + 0.4fr + price column width. What I really want is to be able to specify the total width of the spacer divs and price so that I can make the Price and Discount columns the same width.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: if it is a table, why not use `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A table might be better for your needs (and accessibility).

This might be what you are looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="product-table">
  <thead>
    <th class="f-head">Item</th>
    <th class="m-head">Price</th>
    <th class="l-head">Discount</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column">Widget A</td>
    <td class="middle-column">2.00</td>
    <td class="last-column">0.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column">Widget B</td>
    <td class="middle-column">2,000.00</td>
    <td class="last-column">2.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first-column">Widget C</td>
    <td class="middle-column">3,000,000.00</td>
    <td class="last-column">3,000.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.product-table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.product-table > th {
  text-align: center;
}

.first-column {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

.f-head {
  background-color: lightcyan;
  width: 20%;
}

.middle-column {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.m-head {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.last-column {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.l-head {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

With table-layout as `fixed`, the column width is defined by each `th` widths. Every non-specified 'th' width will be `auto`.

**But... in case you insist on that structure, in spite of everything else:**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="product-table">
    <div id="f-column">
      <div><div class="head">Item</div></div>
      <div class="cell">Widget A</div>
      <div class="cell">Widget B</div>
      <div class="cell">Widget C</div>
    </div>
    <div id="m-column">
      <div class="head m-head">Price</div>
      <div class="m-column-numbers">
        <div class="cell"><div class="m-cell">2.00</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="m-cell">2,000.00</div></div>
        <div class="cell"><div class="m-cell">3,000,000.00</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="l-column">
      <div class="head">Discount</div>
      <div class="cell">0.50</div>
      <div class="cell">2.50</div>
      <div class="cell">3,000.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}
.product-table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.head {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.m-head {
  text-align: center;
}

#f-column {
  background: lightcyan;
  flex: 1;
}

#m-column {
  background: lightsalmon;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.m-column-numbers {
  width: max-content;
}

#l-column {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  text-align: right;
}

.cell {
  width: 100%;
}

.m-cell {
  text-align: right;
}
```

This provides the structure, but it will complicate the dynamic population of data and it has no accessibility at all.

[image: Solution screenshot]

Comment: Neither of these approaches seems to do what I want. I replaced the image of what I'm trying to achieve in my original post to try to make it clearer. The Price and Discount columns should have equal widths and the prices need to be right aligned to each other in the center of the Price column.

Comment: @ChrisGulley I've seen the new image, I think I got it. The thing is: you don't want the price's width to be the columns width (in orange), but rather to be only based on the biggest price width, which would be an equivalent to "max-content" or something, right? If that's it, I'll edit my response to provide that option also.

Comment: @r-b-westphalen Yes, visually the price and discount columns should have the same width. Within the price column, the column of numbers should have the width of the widest price and be centered in the column.

Comment: @ChrisGulley check it out :)

Comment: @r-b-westphalen This seems to produce the layout I want but it is using flexbox and the original question is how to do this using a grid layout. I'm working with an existing codebase that generates the HTML programmatically. If you compare the HTML in the original question to the HTML in the flexbox solution you can see that the grid solution maps more cleanly to the original data. Obviously I can change the code to translate the row-based data into columns for the flexbox solution, but I was looking for a way to use the existing grid-based solution.